# Business logic in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my first question here so I'm really open for opinions, I searched a lot about ASP.NET Core MVC and still I don't have enough answers if I'm writing code in right way.

In many tutorials on Youtube I saw people create ASP.NET Core MVC applications with CRUD operations but there were just simple without any logic and all code was in controllers.

What if I want add some logic for example checking if my record already exists in the database? Where should I put this?

I have class Patient and I want add patient to database so I got in patient controller this :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("PatientId,Name,Surname,Pesel")] Patient patient)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
          String result =  facade.Add_patient(patient);

          if (result == "Patient added")
          {
               _context.Add(patient);
               await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
               return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
          }
          else
          {
               ViewBag.Message = "Patient exists";
               return View();
          }
    }
}
```

Facade is my class in model folder where I have this :

```
public class Facade
{
    private Database_controller _context;

    public Facade(Database_controller context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    private List<Patient> patients = new List<Patient>();

    public List<Patient> Patients { get => patients; set => patients = value; }

    public void updatedata()
    {
        patients = _context.Patients.ToList();
    }

    public string Add_patient(Patient patient)
    {
        Patient Patient = new Patient();
        Patient.Name = patient.Name;
        Patient.Surname = patient.Surname;
        Patient.Pesel = patient.Pesel;
        String if_is = addpacjent(Patient);

        if (!"Is".Equals(if_is))
        {
            return "Patient added";
        }
        else
        { 
            return "Patient exists"; 
        }
    }

    public String addpacjent(Patient val)
    {
        bool if_is = patients.Contains(val);

        if (if_is == true)
        {
            return ("Is");
        }
        else
        {
            patients.Add(val);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In `Patient` class is override method equals for checking

```
 public override bool Equals(Object ob)
 {
        String Name = Surname;
        String Name2 = ((Patient)ob).Surname;
        String Pesel1 = Pesel;
        String Pesel2 = ((Patient)ob).Pesel;
        bool a = Name.Equals(Name2);

        if (Pesel2 != "0")
        {
            bool b = Pesel1.Equals(Pesel2);
            bool c = false;

            if (a && b == true)
            {
                c = true;
            }

            return c;
        }
        else 
            return a;
}
```

Is it the right way? Should I have method `_context.Add(patient)` in `Facade` or controller? Where should I check existence in database?

I already have application which I want write in .NET Core in Winforms so I want use as many as possible code from Winforms classes so it's why I started coding like this in ASP.NET Core MVC

Comment: Do some research on the repository pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `Any()`,this is because `Any()` will return as soon as it finds a match.

Like my following:

```
 public IActionResult Test()
    {
       //Simulation data:

        var patient = new Patient
        {
          Name="AA",
          SumName="AA-aa",
          Pesel="23"
        };

       //Here you can add your conditions.

        if (!_context.Patients.Any(o => o.Name == patient.Name&&o.SumName==patient.SumName&&o.Pesel==patient.Pesel))
        {
            _context.Add(patient);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Patient exists";
            return View();
        };
        
    }
```

Below is the demo data in my database:

[image]

Sample effect display:
[image]

Comment: This is the easiest way.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I had an idea before to use  this `code_context.Patients.SingleOrDefault(patient1 => patient1.Surname == patient.Surname && patient1.Pesel == patient.Pesel); `code   but it's still right? I read that logic should not be in controllers, controllers should be thin. What if i would have more "logic" to introduce?

Comment: That kind of code is wrong, it is not a judgment condition. If you want to use that kind of code, you need to judge whether the patient you have inquired about exists.

Comment: Like I said,`Any() `will return as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: If you want to implement more logic, you can go to the relevant content of the `repository`.

Comment: Ye I know, I just forget paste all code `code Patient patient1 = _context.Patients.SingleOrDefault(patient1 => patient1.Surname == patient.Surname && patient1.Pesel == patient.Pesel);    if (!_context.Patients.Contains(patient1))
                    {_context.Add(patient);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
               return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));} `code   <--- that was my idea but I didn't know if it is suitable for MVC pattern, your code is shorter so i will use this and read more about repository pattern, 
because I haven't heard about it before. Thanks

Comment: Yes, using Any() is the easiest way. I am glad to help you.